# RPC Request for get-schema of bbf(broadband forum) yangs

Tags: ietf-netconf, netconf, yang

I am trying below RPC request for module bbf-dot1q-types. but facing error like identifier is not found.
Please help me on this to what is the right RPC request for bbf yangs.

```
<rpc xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="1">
 <get-schema xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-netconf-monitoring">
   <identifier>bbf-dot1q-types</identifier>
 </get-schema>
</rpc>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rpc-reply message-id="1" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
    <rpc-error>
        <error-type>application</error-type>
        <error-tag>invalid-value</error-tag>
        <error-severity>error</error-severity>
        <error-info>
            <err-element>identifier</err-element>
        </error-info>
        <error-message>
            MINOR: MGMT_CORE #2301: Invalid element value
        </error-message>
    </rpc-error>
</rpc-reply>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the Netconf server handling your request does not have the **bbf-dot1q-types** module loaded. See [RFC 6022, 3.1.  The <get-schema> Operation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6022#page-8):

> If the requested schema does not exist, the <error-tag> is 'invalid-value'.

Make sure the Netconf server loads the module.